# how to update an attribute value that contains html encoded characters

Tags: xml, bash, xmlstarlet

I am updating a log pattern attribute in a Tomcat configuration XML file (`server.xml`). My `xmlstarlet` command updates the attribute correctly, but I have an issue with inserting HTML-encoded characters, like `&quot;`.

This is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on"/>

  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443"/>
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>
      <Host name="localhost">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" pattern="UPDATE-THIS"/>
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

This is my `xmlstarlet` command:

```
xmlstarlet edit \
    --update "/Server/Service[@name='Catalina']/Engine[@name='Catalina']/Host[@name='localhost']/Valve[@className='org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve']/@pattern" -v "%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" \
    "$CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml"
```

The command above updates the pattern this way:

```
"%h %l %u %t &amp;quot;%r&amp;quot; %s %b"
```

I would like to have this:

```
"%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b"
```

As you can see there are extra `&amp;` chars around the `&quot;%r&quot;`.

What is the proper way to update an attribute value with HTML-encoded chars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to append `| xmlstarlet unesc` to your command to unescape special XML characters.